# Is there a dynamic way to check values in typescript

Tags: typescript, type-declaration

[TL:DR]
I want to create

```
type ExtendedValueTypes = 'money' | 'land' | 'money_max' | 'land_max';
// dynamically from
type ValueTypes = 'money' | 'land';
```

I have a list of values

```
const values = ['money', 'land'] as const;
type ValueTypes = typeof values[number];
// equals ValueTypes = 'money' | 'land';
```

Now I want to dynamically extend my type to equal

```
type ExtendedValueTypes = 'money' | 'money_max' | 'land' | 'land_max';
```

I don't want to have two separate arrays/types to maintain so I would like to have some type declaration that extends all strings in my type with '_max'.

```
const check = (type: ValueTypes) => 'some return'

//works
check('money');

// does not work but should
check('money_max')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to manipulate string literal types this way:

```
type ExtendedValueTypes = ValueTypes | `${ValueTypes}_max`
// type ExtendedValueTypes = ValueTypes | "money_max" | "land_max"


const check = (type: ExtendedValueTypes) => 'some return'

//works
check('money');

//works
check('money_max');
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=4.7.2&ssl=13&ssc=19&pln=3&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QCrggZygXigcgFsB7AOwhHygB8CE5SATfAbgCg3RIoBRAD2AQmERvGRoM2PGJTpI2WgAMAJAG8ZE+QF8A+oTh9FbAPTGoXaP0HDRiWZNyw7mrDSgAiEuRB6D7t+70TL587hxsAMZkmMBQEQAWEBEA1o4AFBYAXLwCQowiGnJYAJS4AHwEmMSE0ABOEMBItaT4HKYA7sS1yZiRiSlpRGQU+MXsJsad3b0JScmDXhQho0A)

Comment: That is possible?!
Thanks so much. Knowing this will solve so much :)